# Position fixed div, dynamic height, alignement of images in ul

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

So, I have a div, position fixed, with a static width and a height of 100%.
Inside that div, I would like to horizontally split an ul containing images (inside links).

Html structure:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="icon.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="icon.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="icon.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
html *, body * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

div {
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  height: 33.333333333%;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  height: 60%;
}
```

But, how can I set the vertical alignement. I've tried many ways of using vertical-align (or other tricks), but nothing happens, surely because of the positioning fixed. Should I choose another solution ?

Also, in Chrome when the window is resized on height, the images stretches rather than conserve proportions.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/muxisar/4F7Zm/

Comment: For starters, the CSS in your JSFiddle is slightly different to the CSS you posted here, which is correct?

Comment: Thanks. Edited with the last version. There is still some differences, like borders and list-style.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve vertical centering by converting the a element into a table with display and setting display table-cell on the img.

```
a {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

To get the scaling, you need to set heights on the a and li too.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwzTU/12/

Comment: Yeah, sounds good. Except when the window (so the body) is resized in height: It seems that the space above the images is always the same size. Is it fixable ?

Comment: Oh. It doesn't work in Firefox ? Images don't follow the height: 80%.

Comment: It's proving tricky to get cross-browser scaling using the display: table approach...may need a re-think.